# Program to find the smallest number evenly divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20

Tags: python

Following is the code I tried to calculate the solution for the stated problem. But it returns nothing. What's wrong with my code ?

```
flag = False
i = 20
while flag==False:
    c = 0    
    for x in range(1,21):
        if i%x==0:
            c = c + 1
    if c==20:
        print i
        flag = True
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: By saying it returns nothing, do you mean it never terminates (that code could take a long time to run!) or what? Does it ever print a number? How have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the LCM of a list of given numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237954/calculate-the-lcm-of-a-list-of-given-numbers-in-python)

Comment: `c` is never 20 when you come out of the `for x` loop.  Add a `print(c)` just before the `if c==20` to see that you have an endless loop which never reaches 20. (Probably pipe to `less` or something so you don't flood your terminal.)

Comment: As an aside, you should not be learning Python 2 any more. Python 3 is the supported, recommended version of the language. Version 2 was slated to be end-of-lifed earlier this year, though it got a couple of extra years in terminal care in an unfortunate compromise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my code in python. We can simply do it by like this.
    import fractions

```
def lcm(n):
    x=1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x = (x*i)/fractions.gcd(x,i)
    return x

ans = lcm(20)
print(ans)
```